# Strange xpages error

Tags: internet-explorer, runtime-error, xpages

In an application developed on xpages, which has been in production for two months, a specific document loads partially, and the user edit the following message appears:

The form does not contain an input: $$ viewid and xpages

The problem only happens in IE, Chrome runs smoothly.

What might be the possible cause of the error? I am suspicious that it is related to a rich text field, in which the user pasted some tables. Can be it?

I discovered that the cause of the problem is the user's pasted tables in html format in the text risk field. As I had reported the problem does not happen in chrome, only in IE. There's how to avoid it in IE.

Comment: You have a better chance if you provide source code that shows the issue

Comment: Have you added your own form tag to the XPage?

Comment: Hi, have you checked the richtext content ? if it contains a <form> it might break your xpage....

Comment: The rich text content has several HTML tables, but I did not notice any tag breaks.

Comment: I have not added any tags to the xpages

Comment: I can not post the code because the content is stealthy.